# Session cannot get photo and username

Tags: php, session

I have created a session called profileinfo which it stores the photo and also the username, but it only works for once only, after i click on another tab its sending the session data. Are there any ways to do this?

This is my index.php code:

```
session_start();
$name = $auth_info['profile']['displayName'];
$address = $auth_info['profile']['address']['formatted'];
$photo = $auth_info['profile']['photo'];

$_SESSION['profileinfo'] = array($name, $address, $photo);

$redirect = "http://localhost/cm0655-assignment/fanzine.php?photo=".$photo."&displayName=".$name;
header('Location: '.$redirect);
```

This is my another page where i called the session data but its not working:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['profileinfo'])){
    echo "<li><a href=\"fanzine.php\">Fanzine</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href=\"vcinfo.php\">Virtual Club House</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
    echo "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">";
    echo "<li style=\"float:right;list-style-type:none;\">";
    echo "<a class=\"janrainEngage\" href=\"#\">";
    echo "<img src=".$_GET['photo']. " height=\"30\" width=\"30\"/>";
    echo $_GET['displayName'];
    echo "</a></li></ul>";
}else{
    echo "<li><a class=\"janrainEngage\" href=\"#\">Login</a></li>";
}
```

This the error message i am getting when i clicked on the another page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: photo in 
Notice: Undefined index: displayName in
```

Are there anyways to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add `session_start()` at the top of your second page?

Answer (score 1):

If your `$photo` contains url, you should use `base64_encode`. You cant submit an url as query.

```
session_start();
$name = $auth_info['profile']['displayName'];
$address = $auth_info['profile']['address']['formatted'];
$photo = base64_encode($auth_info['profile']['photo']);

$_SESSION['profileinfo'] = array($name, $address, $photo);

$redirect = "http://localhost/cm0655-assignment/fanzine.php?photo=".$photo."&displayName=".$name;
header('Location: '.$redirect);
```

On second page, use base64_decode to decode your photo :

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['profileinfo'])){
    echo "<li><a href=\"fanzine.php\">Fanzine</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href=\"vcinfo.php\">Virtual Club House</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
    echo "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">";
    echo "<li style=\"float:right;list-style-type:none;\">";
    echo "<a class=\"janrainEngage\" href=\"#\">";
    echo "<img src=".base64_decode($_GET['photo']). " height=\"30\" width=\"30\"/>";
    echo $_GET['displayName'];
    echo "</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>";

}else{
    echo "<li><a class=\"janrainEngage\" href=\"#\">Login</a></li>";

}
```

Comment: actually thats not the prb.. the prb is i cant pass the `$_SESSION['profileinfo]` to a third page. I can only pass it to the second page only.

Comment: @anonymous5671 Did you noticed session_start(); above of the second code block ? Can you try with this way and see Is it ok.